# How to get 100% of coverage on lambda method [JAVA]

Tags: java, lambda, code-coverage, jacoco

I tried everything to get 100% of coverage on this lambda method but no matter what I do I don't get it.

```
private String createMessage(List<FieldError> erros) {
    return erros.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(FieldError::getField, FieldError::getDefaultMessage, (keyOld, keyNew) -> keyOld)).toString();
}
```

[image: IMG1]

[image: IMG2]

Comment: I tried a standard set of test cases using your code (empty list, single item, multiple items, items with duplicate keys) and achieved 100% coverage with the coverage tool built in to IntelliJ. I haven't tried with jacoco. It could well be an issue with jacoco's handling of lambdas. Have you tried another tool?

Comment: The only test that I didn't do was duplicate keys. That the only one was missing

Comment: That optional third argument to `toMap` is specifically to handle merging keys which is why it isn't exercised if you don't test with duplicate keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uncovered code is the implementation of a lambda expression. You only have one lambda expression `(keyOld, keyNew) -> keyOld`, which means that that code doesn't get executed.

The lambda expression is the 3rd argument to [`Collectors.toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), i.e. `BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction`, which is documented as *"a merge function, used to resolve collisions between values associated with the same key"*.

If there are no collisions in the data, the lambda expression won't get executed, so make sure you test the code with data where the `erros` list contains 2 or more elements with the same `getField()` value.